# jQuery UI dialog widget not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

For the last two days I've been trying to understand why I can't build a jQuery Dialog. I am trying to integrate it into another project but I couldn't so I created a new test html page for the sole purpose of building a simple one that works. I've tried multiple configurations and nothing works. I've attempted it on [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avicenna_x/ykGNH/) and it works (on an older version, mind) leading me to assume I've messed up my headers.

```
<script src="../jQuery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="..jQuery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jQuery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jQuery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jQuery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.structure.css">
```

`test.js` contains jquery code as seen in js fiddle link above. Am I missing anything? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: You have a typo. `..jQuery` should be `../jQuery`. Is that in the production code or just a copying error.

Comment: Good call. That was the issue. Sloppy coding is the culprit again..

Comment: How come you didn't notice the error in the console?

Comment: You should consider using some kind of dependancy manager, because this is extremely fault prone. If you change folder structure, your page will break and you'll have to update all the urls yourself. I would also recommend using CDN URLs over your local machine/server ones, unless you have really good connection (this goes if your website will be accessed by lots of users).